# Generating Db Versions

Tags: subsonic

I am trying to generate dbVersion using SubSonic but when I execute the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SubSonic\SubSonic 2.1 Final\SubCommander\sonic.exe
    version /out Generated\dbVersions\
```

I receive the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly `'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio installed?

Comment: Yes I have Sql Management Studio Installed on my System

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess you're using SQL 2008? Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc284267.aspx

You need to pull down the CLR objects as well as Native types (the answer is at the bottom):

"Downloading these resolved the issue
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en
From Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, August 2008:
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects
"